# Cómo puedo generar un token en Jmeter y luego usarlo como variable?

Tags: jmeter

soy relativamente nueva en Jmeter y estoy en el proceso de creación de un script donde necesito desde él abrir la línea de comandos, generar un token mediante "java -jar tokengenerator-1.1.jar ${rutPersona}" y luego, una vez generado este, extraer el token y usarlo como variable más adelante en la ejecución. Quería saber si alguien podría tener ideas para probar o si sabe cómo solucionarlo, estoy intentando con un OS Process Sampler pero no logro hacer lo que quiero y creo que puede ser porque no entiendo bien ese muestreador. En caso de que alguien haya tenido que hacer algo similar, sepa cómo hacerlo o tenga ideas de cómo podría solucionar este problema se los agradecería enormemente.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.